# Showing a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a surjective and continuous

Tags: general-topology

Given an open set $U$ (in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$) and a function $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, I would like to show that, assuming $f$ is injective (1 to 1) and continuous:

$f^{-1}$ is continuous

I tried proving by contradiction. Assuming that there exists such a point $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that for every $(u_x,u_y)\in U$ :  $f(u_x,u_y)\neq (x,y)$. Now I feel like I should use the fact that $f$ is continuous, somehow construct an open set $V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $(x,y)\in V$ and then getting that $f^{-1} [V]$ is not an open set in $U$, but I fail to find such $V$.

Am I on the right path? Or any other ideas would be very welcome!

Thanks!

Edit: Regarding to $(2)$ - isn't it true simply because $f$ is continuous and $f^{-1}$ exists? ($f^{-1}$ exists because $f$ is bijective)

Comment: Some hypotheses are missing, there is no reason for $f$ to be surjective (take for instance the identity on $U=B(0,1)$).

Comment: I dont think so, the continuity of $f$ should be enough. Regarding to your example, if I got you right-here's $U$: [pic1](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/09/23/topo001.png). Assuming $f$ is the identity function, we should get a situation in which for each open set $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ the reverse image $f^{-1}[V]$ is an open set as well. Same goes for closed sets. Lets take a closed set $V$ such as in here [pic2](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/09/23/topo002.png) (the green square).The reverse image is neither open nor closed, in contradiction to $f$ being continuous.

Comment: The preimage of the closed green square is actually closed, it is the intersection of that square with $B_1(0)$, and this is closed in $B_1(0)$ by the definition of the subspace topology (the usual topology on the open unit ball is the topology it inherits from the plane).

Comment: Actually $f^{-1}(V)$ is closed in $U$ (Its complement in $U$ is open).

Comment: **Every** inclusion is - if the subset is equipped with the subspace topology - injective and continuous. It is surjective if and only if the subset is not a proper one (quite exceptional).

Comment: Denis's counterexample is valid. If $f:U \to \mathbb R^2$ is continuous, and $V$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$, then $f^{-1}(V)$ is open _in_ $U$. It doesn't have to be open in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @Denis - You are right, I didn't understand the question well, re-edited it. Now the onto part is trivial, and all is left is $(2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) This ins't true as for instance for every proper subset of $\mathbb R^2$ the identity of $V$ isn't surjective

(2) If we restrict to the image of f then 
$$f:V\rightarrow f(V)$$
is biyective and indeed it'is an homeomorphism, but it's not simply because $f$ is continuous and $f^{−1}$ exists.This is not enough in general topological spaces, but
in $\mathbb R^n$ we have the [Invariance of Domain theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain)so in this case it's true.

Comment: Yes, this theorem is exactly what I'm trying to prove in here. The only problem is how - I've searched for a proof, but didn't find an understandable one (the on in [here](http://pi.unl.edu/~mbrittenham2/classwk/872s07/lecnotes/slides.from.class/cls26--invariance.domain.pdf) is too complicated). Is there any simpler proof for the theorem? Thanks!